# Import cheerio module to TypeScript app

Tags: typescript, cheerio

I try to import `cheerio` to my `typescript` based app.

```
import {cheerio}  from 'cheerio';
console.log(cheerio); //undefined
```

from package.json:

```
...
"@types/cheerio": "^0.22.5
...
```

Comment: Can you include the error you are given when it does not work please

Answer (score 35):

It works for me `import * as cheerio from 'cheerio';`

Answer (score 4):

it's exported as defalut. try

> import cheerio from 'cheerio'

Answer (score 2):

1 - install cheerio

```sh
npm i cheerio
```

2 - import the whole package

```
import cheerio from 'cheerio'
```

**Note**: you can also just import the `load` function

```
import { load } from 'cheerio'
```